# Not able to delete datas from SQLite3

Tags: sqlite, owncloud

I'd like to delete datas on my database using SQLite3 but it doesn't work.

My table : `select * from oc_groups;`

Result :

```
gid
----
Salarie
Compte classe 6/7
Bilan / Compte de resultat
```

My query : `delete from oc_groups where guid = "Compte classe 6/7"`

Result : I get no errors. But my new select return the same list and I don't have any joins...

**Edit #1:**

Query : `sqlite> select hex(gid) from oc_groups;`

Result :

```
hex(gid) = 61646D696E

hex(gid) = 42696C616E202F20636F6D70746520646520726573756C746174

hex(gid) = 436F6D70746520636C6173736520362F37

hex(gid) = 436120636F6E766F63202F20636F6D7074652072656E6475

hex(gid) = 414720636F6E766F63202F20636F6D7074652072656E6475

hex(gid) = 42696C616E202F20636F6D7074652064652072C3A973756C746174

hex(gid) = 53616C617269C3A9
```

**Edit #2**

Resolved with : `delete from oc_groups where hex(gid) = "42696C616E202F20636F6D7074652064652072C3A973756C746174";`

Comment: Show the output of `select hex(guid) from oc_groups;`.

Comment: See edit#1 with your query and the results.

Comment: There are not any hidden or wrongly encoded characters. Please show  the output of `select distinct typeof(guid) from oc_groups;`.

Comment: I solved the problem using the `hex()` function in the delete statement... See edit #2 for the solution.

Comment: That is a silly solution. The problem might simply be a wrong type.

Comment: Your examples are inconsistent; once the column is named "gid", then "guid" in the query. And the hex code you gave is for the text "Bilan / Compte de resultat", not "Compte classe 6/7". I tend to agree with @CL.; the actual issue is probably somehwere else, and possibly you didn't give us the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try using correct quotes and see what happens - strings should be enclosed in single quotes, not double.